# Using both if and for in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have an array, a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], and I am trying to find the index of all the values which are less than 6 and greater than 2, using list comprehension.
I am using the following technique:

```
tk = [b if (a[b]>=2 & [b]<=6) for b in range(len(a))]
```

It keeps saying that there is a syntax error at 'for'.
Any idea how to resolve this? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you meant [b for b in range(len(a)) if (a[b]>=2 & a[b]<=6)]

Comment: `[b for b in range(len(a)) if a[b]>=2 and a[b]<=6]`

Comment: @Himanshu Yeah, that's what I meant. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 3):

This should be enough to do the trick:

```
>>> indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if 2 < x < 6]
>>> indices
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I literally added that 10 seconds before you commented :-)

Comment: Explanation: Conditionals go *after* the `for x in y` part of the list comprehension. The order is `[thingtoproduce for loopvar in iterable if condition]`, not the OP's `[thingtoproduce if condition for loopvar in iterable]`.

Comment: This helped. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 2):

Below code will work

```
  tk = [b for b in range(len(a)) if (a[b]>= 2 and a[b] <= 6)]
  tk
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I have modified 3 things here:

1. way we should call list comprehension with if condition
2. rather than using [b] used a[b]
3. used **and** rather than **&**

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

The placement of the condition in a comprehension has always been a point of much confusion to me as well, so I came up with a working mnemonic device.

If you are excluding elements from the list, `if` belongs to the loop, and goes after the `for`:

```
[item for item in items if condition]
```

If you are deciding between values, that's just a normal [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), which appears as part of the comprehension before the `for`:

```
[item1 if condition else item2 for item1, item2 in items]
```

Your case is clearly the first one since you are excluding elements. The test should therefore go after the `for`, with appropriate syntax fixes:

```
tk = [b for b in range(len(a)) if (2 <= a[b] <= 6)]
```

It might be more intuitive to implement the same operation using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the indices instead of [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range):

```
tk = [item for index, item in enumerate(a) if 2 <= index <= 6]
```